# why is the 'this' pointer dereferenced when returning by reference for operator assignment?

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading, return-by-reference

When overloading assignment operators i have noticed that many examples return by reference and then return a deferenced 'this' pointer like so:

```
Myclass &operator=(const Myclass &rhs){
    if(this==&rhs)
        return *this;
    value=rhs.value;
    return *this;
}
```

What I dont understand is why doesn't it return just the pointer 'this' without dereferencing it, since the value of a pointer is an address?
surely returning a dereferenced pointer returns the value being pointed to and not the address as specified with the & in the header.

Comment: That's done so that you can chain calls to operators. And the `&` in the return type means *reference*, *not* address. C++ uses a context sensitive grammar, the same syntax can have different meaning in different contexts. Like, in some contexts `&` means "address of", in other contexts it means "reference".

Comment: This is how references work. Consider `int x; int &y = x;` (note the lack of `&` before `x`).

Answer (score 2):

If you change the return type of your function to `MyClass*` then you can return `this` without dereferencing it.  `this` is a pointer and you can only return it as a pointer unless you dereference it.

Comment: I don't really feel like this answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

By doing it with references, we can write things like

```
Myclass a;
Myclass b;
Myclass c;

c = b = a;
```

On the other hand if we had:

```
Myclass* operator=(const Myclass &rhs){
    if(this==&rhs)
        return *this;
    value=rhs.value;
    return this;
}
```

Then the result of `b = a` is a Myclass *pointer* which is usually not directly assignable to a `Myclass` instance. It would end up as the equivalent of

```
Myclass a;
Myclass b;
Myclass c;

Myclass* temp = b = a;
c = temp;         // compile error here
```

Then at best we could do:

```
c = *(b = a);
```

which is definitely more awkward.